# How to use slidify with impress.js

Tags: r, impress.js, slidify

Following https://twitter.com/ramnath_vaidya/status/274636089715740672 slidify should support impress.js.
But when I use

```
---
title       : Test
subtitle    : 
author      : 
job         : 
framework   : impressjs  # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
---
```

as head of my Rmd-file (impressjs as in https://raw.github.com/ramnathv/slidify/gh-pages/samples/impressjs/index.Rmd) I get an empty directory in libraries/frameworks called impressjs.

Where do I have to enable impress.js? Do I have to install impress.js prior to using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to use the branch "dev" of the respository:

```
install_github("slidify", "ramnathv", ref="dev")
install_github("slidifyLibraries", "ramnathv", ref="dev")
```

Comment: Yes. I will be merging the features of the dev branch into the master shortly, and then it will be available from there, but for now you will have to install it from the dev branch.

Comment: You can go ahead and accept your own answer so that this question can be closed.