# R how to create a tabulated layout in slidify

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidify

I fail to create tabs in my slidify slide like in an [io2012 example](http://ramnathv.github.io/slidifyExamples/examples/io2012/#6) using the following code

```
---
title: Slidify Test
author: Novice
widgets: [mathjax, bootstrap, quiz]
--- {class: class, tpl: tabs}

This is to test if the tab template works correctly

*** {class: active, id: problem}

Tab1

*** {id: questions}

Tab2
```

As were advised [in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259455/customizing-slide-layouts-in-slidify) I've copied the `tabs.html` to the `assets/layouts` folder (the same as in `io2012`), but still don't see tabs. What is missing? The same experiment with twocols layout worked out.

Another related question - if I choose not to use tabs, how can I create links (transitions) between different slides (for example, to create table of contents)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that now tabs is a dev feature, so to make it work use a dev version (like [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616854/how-to-use-slidify-with-impress-js))

```
install_github("slidify", "ramnathv", ref="dev")
install_github("slidifyLibraries", "ramnathv", ref="dev")
```

Still wondering how to refer from one slide to another..